# score labelling at the right of question

Tags: numbering

I would like to label scores at the right of the question but I don't know what command to use. The following image is the result that I want. I want the [5] appears align with the question and at the right. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Comment: Is there any code to show?

Comment: I don't have. Because I don't even know what code to write.

Comment: Then use `exam` documentclass. For details run `texdoc exam` from terminal.

Comment: Besides using the exam documentclass, is there any command i can use?

Comment: If alignment won't be a problem, add `\hfill [5]` to the end of that item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a sample code using `exam` class.

```
\documentclass[10pt,addpoints,answers]{exam}
\begin{document}

\uplevel{\centering\bfseries\underline{PART -- A} \\Answer all questions}

\begin{questions}

\pointsinrightmargin
\pointsdroppedatright
\marksnotpoints
%\marginpointname{mark}
\pointpoints{mark}{marks}
\pointformat{\themarginpoints}
\bracketedpoints

\question[4]
Some question here you would like to ask your students.
\droppoints

\question[4]
Some question here you would like to ask your students.
\droppoints

\uplevel{\centering OR}

\question
What are
\begin{parts}
\part[5]
marks
\droppoints
\part[5]
good answers
\droppoints
\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes.
The code using \text will be as follows
code:

`\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
\text{$3. Using ~{} the~{} substitution$ $x$ $$=$$ $2sec~\sl{t},$}\\
\text{~{}show that} \\
\text{~{}$\int_{2}^{4} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}dx$ $=$ $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{32}$ $\qquad \qquad$ $(5) $}
\end{equation*}
\end{document`

[image: label1]

Answer (score 0):

You can arrive the solution as shown below

code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
3.~{}By~{} using~{} the~{} substitution~{} x &= 2sec~\sl{t},\\
show that \\
 \int_{2}^{4} \frac{\sqrt{x^2-4}}{x^4}dx &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{32} \qquad \qquad (5) 
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

output:
[image: label]

Comment: Do you know about `\text`?

Comment: what does \qquad mean/stand for?