# Putting points at the bottom right corner of the question

Tags: exam, article, points

I am preparing an exam and want to state the score to the relevant question in the very next line at the bottom right corner of the statement of the question, like `[5 points]`.

I looked at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203430/score-labelling-at-the-right-of-question), which is created in the `exam` environment. I've already prepared the exam in `article` class with each question under `\begin{enumerate} ...... \end{enumerate}`.

Any help in achieving this is much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show a Minimal Working Example with a fake question?  If each question is an \item, try ending with `\hfill [5 ponts]` or `\par\noindent\makebox[\linewidth][r]{[5 points]}`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo, thank you, it worked on a new line. When I used \hfill [5 points] it appeared in the same line. But similar  [5 points] were not right-aligned. Can you please tell me how to get that work too. Thanks again.

Comment: `\hfill` expands to fill the available space, overpowering the automatic `\hfil` (`\parendfil` IIRC) at the end of a paragraph.  The `\makebox` is intended to take up an entire line `[\linewidth]` and display the contents right justified `[r]`.